# sound device 302 three channel mixer

Tags: mixers

Hey guys I was wondering if you could help me I have been getting to know the sound device 302 three channel mixer and what I would really like to do is send three channels separately from it, maybe with two of the channels as a stereo pair and the third on its own, like when one is recording 4channels on a recorder.
Does anyone know if this is possible? Right now all i can get is all three in the same stereo pair, I can send one channel left and a second right but still have a third.

The device does have a third return slot for mini jack cables but that seams to be made for any extra mixers that one would plug into the 302 and be called the 4th and 5th channel. 
Does any one know a solution for me?

The only way I can think of using it is with on wireless left one wireless right and a boom centre, and in a case where one wireless sound gets ruined by clothes or what ever use the other channel. But I would really like all three microphones to have their own recording.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: The mini-jack output is for camera feed, in a film setting quite handy. You can then monitor the audio coming back in from the camera. You have to either use cable, or wireless. But i guess you're using it for sfx recording?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I agree with @Cédric, there's no way you can do that with any 3 channel mixer.

Secondly, @Gaelan, you should just take your two lav channels and have those panned to one side and then take your boom mic and have that panned to the other. While its not total separation, it's still separates the boom from the lavs and still makes your signal a bit manageable.

Answer (score 3):

Hello,

Sorry, it's not possible, the SD 302 has 3 inputs and only 2 outputs. 
It's a mixer not a recorder...